# Should you use S3 when methods would take different arguments?

Tags: r, oop, vector, methods

I'm debating whether to use S3 for a package I'm writing or whether to just create separate functions. Both functions do very similar things but one is intended for use on a single input and the other on a series of inputs and hence have different arguments and return different objects. At first I thought I should use S3 however now I'm leaning towards just creating two separate functions (kind of like how [yardstick](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/index.html) creates separate `{metric}()` and `{metric}_vec()` versions for each of the functions in the package.

Say I have a function like `read_head()` that expects a `file_path` then reads in the file and returns the head of it.

```r
read_head <- function(file_path, n = 10) { 
  readr::read_csv(file_path, n_max = n)
}
```

And that I have another function `read_head_files()` that takes in a dataframe containing a column `file_paths` and creates a new list-column `contents` that contains the head of each file. For example

```r
df_example <- tibble::tibble(file_paths = c("folder/file1.csv", "folder/file2.csv"))

read_head_files <- function(df, n = 10){
  dplyr::mutate(df, contents = purrr::map(file_paths, read_head, n = n) 
}
```

base R S3 generics like `print()`, `str()` etc. suggest that S3 can be used pretty liberally with objects that have reasonably different input and return objects. However then the `yardstick` package example mentioned above makes me think that perhaps in this case it is more appropriate to just create separate functions so that I can expose the argument names directly (note that `yardstick` though *does* use S3 so that matrices, dataframes, tables all have their own methods for dispatch).

I'm curious what the  guidance is on *when* you should use S3 / OOP versus just creating individual functions (and specifically recommendations for the case above)?

Comment: this is an opinion question and will likely be closed for off-topic. but one thing i always consider: why make users learn one function when you could make them [learn 4 instead](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/reference/sens.html) bonus if the same argument takes different data types depending if they use `*_vec` or not

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't quite catch your meaning? It sounded like you were being sarcastic about the 4 functions (my understanding though is `sens()` and `sensitivity()` are the same and it's just to help a user -- similar to how both `dplyr::summarize()` and `summarise()` both exist -- so it's really more just 2 to learn) so are you intimating that the separate functions is a bad idea there? The reason I think they made them into 2 different functions is in part because they take different data types. So are you suggesting that's not a good reason and it'd be better to stick with S3 / fewer funs?